# Bootstrap Modal Does Not Show Up When Clicking On The Button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap simple document goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.2.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-QYIZto+st3yW+o8+5OHfT6S482Zsvz2WfOzpFSXMF9zqeLcFV0/wlZpMtyFcZALm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Ajax To Do List <a href="" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <li class="list-group-item">Crasasd asdas asdas</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Crasasd asdas asdas</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Crasasd asdas asdas</li>
                                <li class="list-group-item">Crasasd asdas asdas</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                        Launch demo modal
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-3">
                </div>

                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have determined the js scripts and css files and it show the list properly in Bootstrap but the Modal does not show up when clicking on **Launch demo modal**.

Also no js error appears in Console bar!

So what's going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You are using HTML written for Bootstrap 4, with the JavaScript of version 5. The attribute names have changed - `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target` are what needs to be set on the trigger button, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/modal/

Comment: @CBroe You're right, I replaced them with `data-bs-*` and now the Modal comes but the now the problem is it does get closed when clicking on **x** button

Comment: You mean the problem is that it does _not_ close? The attribute name on that button also needs changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
data-bs-toggle="modal"
data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
```

and on close you need

```
data-bs-dismiss="modal"
```

on you **Launch demo modal** Button.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/